# Transferring a long list of data to specific sheets based on selection in first cell of each row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate a list of data to be transferred to specific sheets by adding new rows, all within the same workbook.

Ideally I wouldn't like to limit the number of rows of data to be transferred as there could be a large amount of data coming in. I have tried the following code but it only works for a single row of data, can anyone help improve this code to transfer multiple rows?

```
Sub AddValues()

'Dimension variable and declare data type
Dim i As Single

'Save row number of cell below last nonempty cell

i = Worksheets("" & Range("A2")).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Save input values to selected worksheet

Worksheets("" & Range("A2")).Range("B" & i & ":P" & i) = _
Worksheets("Form").Range("B2:P10").Value

'Clear input cells

Worksheets("Form").Range("B2:P10") = ""

'Stop macro

End Sub
```

Sample output of what I hope it do:

[image: Sample]

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. Still you question is not clear... from where to where, how many items...  and there is no mention of whatever you try or research...

Comment: Hello! Sorry about that, I have just tried to make it clearer by updating the image in my entry as an example of what I hope it would be able to achieve - is this clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

EDITED. That one is the last version, fixin the shifting problems from the previous one.
I just add a few comments so in the future you can modify it easily.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddValues()

'Dimension variable and declare data type
Dim i As Long 'Counter
Dim j As Long 'Counter
Dim NextRow As Long 'Last Row used

'Save input values to selected worksheet
For i = 2 To Worksheets("Form").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row 'For Each Row on Sheet "Form"

'If there is no item still copied (Problem with merged cells)

    If Worksheets(Range("A" & i).Value2).Cells(1048576, 2).End(xlUp).Row < 7 Then
        For j = 2 To Worksheets("Form").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
            Worksheets(Range("A" & i).Value2).Cells(7, j).Value2 = Worksheets("Form").Cells(i, j).Value2
        Next j

'If there is just one item still copied (Problem with merged cells)

    ElseIf Worksheets(Range("A" & i).Value2).Cells(1048576, 2).End(xlUp).Row = 7 Then
        For j = 2 To Worksheets("Form").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
            Worksheets(Range("A" & i).Value2).Cells(8, j).Value2 = Worksheets("Form").Cells(i, j).Value2
        Next j

'For all remaining scenarios

    Else
        NextRow = Worksheets(Range("A" & i).Value2).Cells(1048576, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = 2 To Worksheets("Form").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
            Worksheets(Range("A" & i).Value2).Cells(NextRow + 1, j).Value2 = Worksheets("Form").Cells(i, j).Value2
        Next j
    End If

Next i

'Clear input cells from B2 cell until the last Cell (not required to pay attention to the range)

Range(Cells(2, 2), Worksheets("Form").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)) = ""

'End macro


End Sub
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey David, thanks for responding so quickly! I tried using the code but experienced two issues:                                                                                                                  
1) It appears that because of Cells(i + k, i +j), it ends up putting the information off center for every k and j, resulting in the data being loaded diagonally into the target sheet.

2) It only seems to pick one target sheet based on the selection in A2; can this be manipulated so that it can be allocated to the right sheet based on the selection in this column A?

Comment: It's working pretty good actually except for one thing so far which puzzles me: The shifting still exists, so when I run the code, the first sheet it populates is ok, but as it gets into the second and third sheets, it shifts downwards based on the number of rows that were added in the previous sheet.

Comment: The new code seems to remove a row each time so data actually disappears (e.g. Sheet 1, I lose 1 from K=1, then Sheet 2, 2 are lost from K=2 and then in Sheet 3, 3 rows are lost). Additionally it overwrites first row of non-empty cells in the target sheets.

Comment: Thanks David for the help - appreciate your time and effort here. Macro works like a charm! :)